# How to disable sparks empty file $folder$ creation?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

When running spark cluster in AWS EMR, I save some parque file.

When saving the files, spark creates some empty files that contains the word `$folder$` like these:

[image]

These files are saved in S3.

Does any configuration exist to avoid creation of these files?